# Sum $\sum_{x=1}^n\sum _{y=1}^{x-1}\frac{1/2^x*1/2^y}{1/2^x+1/2^y}$

Tags: summation

Is there a way to calculate following summation

$\sum_{x=1}^n\sum _{y=1}^{x-1}\frac{1/2^x*1/2^y}{1/2^x+1/2^y}$

Can it be reduced to something simple?

Comment: Was there meant to be a $y$ in the argument? Or a $j$ in the summation index?

Comment: Did you mean  $\sum_{x=1}^n\sum _{j=1}^{x-1}\frac{1/2^x*1/2^j}{1/2^x+1/2^j}$ ??

Comment: Judging from the first few values, probably not.

Comment: You can simplify the summand to $\frac{1}{2^x+2^y}$.

Comment: If both sums were to start at $0$ rather than $1$, then for $n\to\infty$ we'd get [OEIS A$179951$](http://oeis.org/A179951), for which there is no known closed form.

Answer (score 1):

We can pretty simply reduce the limit as $n\to\infty$ to a single sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac1{2^j+2^k}
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac1{2^j+2^k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{2^j}\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty\frac1{2^{k-j}+1}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{2^j}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k+1}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2^k+1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: change order of summation
$(2)$: factor $2^{-j}$ out of the inner sum
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto k+j$
$(4)$: sum in $j$

I don't see an easy way to simplify the finite sum.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no closed form. However, the double sum converges quite rapidly. Denoting your sum by $T_n$, it is more natural to consider instead the sum
$$ S_n = \sum_{x,y=1}^n \frac{1}{2^x+2^y}. $$
You can check that
$$ T_n = \frac{S_n - \sum_{x=1}^n \frac{1}{2^{x+1}}}{2} = \frac{S_n - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{2}. $$
We can estimate the infinite sum
$$
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{x,y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x+2^y} \\ &\leq
\sum_{x,y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\max(x,y)}} \\ &\leq
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{2m+1}{2^m} = 5.
\end{align*}
$$
The actual value is $S \approx 2.02899956069689$.

The infinite limit of your sum is $T = (S-\tfrac{1}{2})/2 \approx 0.764499780348444$.

How fast is the convergence?
$$
\begin{align*}
S - S_n &\leq 2\sum_{x=n+1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x+2^y} \\ &\leq
2\sum_{x=n+1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{\max(x,y)}} \\ &\leq
2\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \frac{2m+1}{2^m} \\ &= O\left(\frac{n}{2^n}\right).
\end{align*}
$$
You can similarly obtain a bound from the other direction, and deduce that $S_n = S - \Theta(\frac{n}{2^n})$. Therefore $T_n = T - \Theta(\frac{n}{2^n})$.

We can obtain another expression for $T$ using the identity
$$
\frac{1}{2^x+2^y} = \frac{1}{2^x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{2^{n(x-y)}}.
$$
Using this, we get
$$
\begin{align*}
T &= \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{2^x+2^y} \\ &=
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{2^x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{2^{n(x-y)}} \\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{2^{n(x-y)}} \\ &=
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x-1}{2^x} +
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{(n+1)x}} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} 2^{ny} \\ &=
1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{(n+1)x}} \frac{2^{nx}-2^n}{2^n-1} \\ &=
1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n-1} \left[\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x} - 2^n \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{(n+1)x}} \right] \\ &=
1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n-1} \left[1 - \frac{1}{2-2^{-n}}\right] \\ &=
1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}-1} \\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}-1}. 
\end{align*}
$$
We can obtain another expression by opening $1/(2^{n+1}-1)$ into a series:
$$
\begin{align*}
T &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}-1} \\ &=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{(n+1)m}} \\ &=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{(m+1)(n+1)}} \\ &=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{m+1}+1}.
\end{align*}
$$
Summarizing,
$$
T = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}-1} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{m+1}+1}.
$$